# Thunderbird outgoing password

Tags: passwords

Roadrunner/time warner/spectrum now required a password for outgoing mail.  I use a different server for incoming mail. How do I set the outgoing password?
Thunderbird 52.3.0

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, SMTP (outgoing mail dispatch) is busted in my area.   But the Thunderbird config with authenticated outgoing mail that has worked for months for me is this, for outgoing mail, under Tools, Account Settings

[image: Outgoing (SMTP) Tbird config]